# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor];

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using hibernate4 and spring 3 and jsf2.0
for injection my using annotation
i searched for this exception on Google but not find any appropriate solution
here i have posted my logs , application context and dao implementation

```
Here is my logs
> BlockquoteHibernate: select employee0_.empid as empid0_, employee0_.emailId as emailId0_, employee0_.mobileNo as mobileNo0_, employee0_.password as password0_, employee0_.skypeID as skypeID0_, employee0_.userName as userName0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.userName=?
Aug 10, 2012 5:00:28 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: Received 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException' when invoking action listener '#{loginBacking.empLogin}' for component 'j_idt16'
Aug 10, 2012 5:00:28 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:507)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:845)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:411)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy17.empLogin_Service(Unknown Source)
    at com.airwatch.device.backingbeans.LoginBacking.empLogin(LoginBacking.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:84)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:773)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:296)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatisticsImplementor(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1710)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatistics(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1706)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterTransaction(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.afterTransactionCompletion(JdbcTransaction.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:500)
    ... 40 more

Aug 10, 2012 5:00:28 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt10:j_idt16, Message=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
Aug 10, 2012 5:00:28 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:178)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:84)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:773)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:296)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:507)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:845)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:411)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy17.empLogin_Service(Unknown Source)
    at com.airwatch.device.backingbeans.LoginBacking.empLogin(LoginBacking.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatisticsImplementor(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1710)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatistics(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1706)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterTransaction(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.afterTransactionCompletion(JdbcTransaction.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:500)
    ... 40 more

> Blockquote>
```

AND Here is my application context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- .....................................Data Base Related Config............................. -->
    <bean id="DataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>testn</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.airwatch.device.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>



    <!-- ........................DAO and Bussiness Configurations................. -->
    <bean id="loginBussinessImpl" class="com.airwatch.device.bussinessImpl.LoginBussinessImpl">

    </bean>
    <bean id="loginDaoImpl" class="com.airwatch.device.daoImpl.LoginDaoImpl">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This my DAO class implementation

```
    public class LoginDaoImpl implements ILoginDao {

        private Session mSession = null;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value = "SessionFactory")
        private SessionFactory mHibernateSessionFcatory;

        /**
         * @param sessionfactory
         *            the sessionfactory to set
         */
        public void setSessionfactory(SessionFactory sessionfactory) {
            this.mHibernateSessionFcatory = sessionfactory;
        }

        @Override
        public void empLogin_Dao(Employee employee) {

            System.out.println("m in dao");

            mSession = mHibernateSessionFcatory.getCurrentSession();

            System.out.println(employee.getEmpID());

            Query query = mSession
                    .createQuery("from Employee where userName = :username ");
            query.setParameter("username", employee.getUserName());
            List list = query.list();
            // mSession.getTransaction().commit();
            mHibernateSessionFcatory.close();
            mSession.close();

        }

    }
    `
```

Comment: if any one faced this problem please let me know thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Closing the entire session factory `mHibernateSessionFactory.close()` in your DAO code is an obvious no-go.

Also you can't access mSession after the factory has been closed, it is stated in the java docs.

`void org.hibernate.SessionFactory.close() throws HibernateException`

> Destroy this SessionFactory and release all resources (caches,
>   connection pools, etc).
>
> It is the responsibility of the application to ensure that there are
>   no open sessions before calling this method as the impact on those
>   sessions is indeterminate.

If you are using the `getCurrentSession()` method, the typical pattern is to delegate the session opening and closing to Spring and use the [@Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) annotation

```
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void empLogin_Dao(Employee employee) {

            System.out.println("m in dao");

            //Please note that declaring mSession as a class member is another no-no
            //because DAO are typically singletons, so there's only ONE dao and ONE mSession variable 
            //that will be shared by all users - it's possible your class mSession field will be accessed
            //simultaneously, which will lead to an exception
            Session mSession = mHibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            System.out.println(employee.getEmpID());

            Query query = mSession
                    .createQuery("from Employee where userName = :username ");
            query.setParameter("username", employee.getUserName());
            List list = query.list(); 
        }
```

You can read about the rollback policy [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back).

Comment: I Confirm, solved my problem as well. Opening closed session factory (calling openSession) will give  Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor].